# Efficiently creating lots of small c++ objects that need access to "global" object

Tags: c++, design-patterns, performance

A question about c++ design and efficiency... Imagine this code -

```
Database db;

class SmallObject
{
private:
    /* Some small amount of data and functions */
public:
    /* Constructor, more functions */
    void fn1() { /* Code that uses global db to do it's job */ }
    void fn2() { /* Code that uses global db to do it's job */ }
    void fn3() { /* Code that uses global db to do it's job */ }
    void fn4() { /* Code that uses global db to do it's job */ }
};
```

That's nice, efficient and works well. However the database is global state which is bad. It makes it very hard to test the class in isolation etc and means that SmallObject depends on a specific implementation of Database.

So I restructure it this way :-

```
class SmallObject
{
private:
    /* Some small amount of data and functions */
public:
    SmallObject(Database& db) { db_ = db; }

    void fn1() { /* Code that uses global db_ to do it's job */ }
    void fn2() { /* Code that uses global db_ to do it's job */ }
    void fn3() { /* Code that uses global db_ to do it's job */ }
    void fn4() { /* Code that uses global db_ to do it's job */ }
};
```

And perhaps make a factory to create them so I can use them roughly as before.

```
class SmallObjectFactory
{
private:
    Database* db_;
public:
    SmallObjectFactory()
    {
        db_ = new SpecificDatabaseSubclass;
    }

    SmallObject* create() { return new SmallObject(db_); }
};
```

That works too, means that my SmallObject is no longer coupled to the exact database implementatiom but is still convenient to use.

However, imagine  there are 10000 instances of SmallObject. Now each one has a pointer to *the same* Database object in there. That's horribly inefficient, and also I don't feel that duplicating the data so many times is good design...

So, is there some pattern in C++ that allows me to not make Database global and yet allows me not to store duplicate data in each instance of SmallObject?

This is specifically C++ so templates etc, are fine...

Comment: what makes you think having a lot of pointers to an object is inefficient ? The only thing that is duplicated is the database object's memory address, which is rather small.

Comment: I agree with SirDarius, you'll only be using 4-8 bytes / pointer (Depending on your architecture).  So you'd only be using 40-80k extra bytes for 10,000 objects.  Maybe if you were creating million's of these objects it would be a problem.

Comment: Perhaps it's a poor example. it's not the absolute amount of memory but the fact that it might double the amount my objects use. Even more so, it just seems _useless_ to be storing the same identical value in every single instance of my object, and was wondering if there was any reasonable way to avoid that that had not occured to me

Comment: If every single SmallObject ALWAYS will have the same address, I guess a static member would be ok. But then it is ALWAYS the same. If it was something bigger the flyweight class pattern would be ok, but state doesn't get much smaller than a pointer.

Comment: As a side note you can store a DB reference instead of a pointer to save yourself a key stroke :P

Comment: To clarify this, I don't even know that there is a better solution. But I wasn't entirely happy with either alternative I came up with so really wanted to see if I'd missed anything...

Comment: Besides Singleton Pattern, you can also look at **boost::pool** to allocation and deallocation these small objects. [link](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/pool/doc/index.html)

Comment: I'm with Sir Darius and GWW: unless you're operating in memory-constrained conditions, 10k objects (and ~100K) is not even worth worrying about.  Even if it does double the required space.   Unless it's truly a problem, don't solve it.  If it *is* a problem, use the shared static approach.

Comment: I think I agree too. But you know what it's like when you think "is there a better way to do this?" :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for efficiency it may well be the way you are allocating large numbers of small objects and might want to use some kind of pool.

With regards to the database, I would question your coupling and what users of your classes are doing and seeing. Ideally you do not want them to see your implementation detail, which may be an issue if your class has this private "database" member in it although you can forwardly-declare it.

Your constructor should look like:

```
   explicit SmallObject(Database& db) : db_(db) {}
```

You should also handle SmallObjectFactory properly to manage the lifetime of the underlying db member, probably making your class non-copyable or using shared_ptr.

Your other option might be to maintain a collection of small objects and perform functionality that accesses the database through the container rather than the objects. This is a common design pattern but depends on your model.

Comment: My "real" application was far too complex to ask a short question about so I tried to make it more generic so I could ask a short question. You can treat Database as an abstract interface so it shouldn't introcuce any coupling to specific implementations.

Answer (score 2):

You could define a static `db` property in the `SmallObject` class and assign your DB to it at runtime. Then, all instances of `SmallObject` can use this property without needing to have copies of pointers to it.

Comment: Having said that, if you're shooting for efficiency, it is acceptable to write ugly code (i.e. using globals would be just fine).

Answer (score 2):

You could use a [Singleton Pattern](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Singleton_pattern) if you use a unique database.

Comment: To be honest if I'm going to do that, or use a static members varioable as someone else suggested then it feels like I may as well just use a global variable. It maybe that there is no good solution and it;s not really a problem :)

Answer (score 2):

Pattern is called FlyWeight, if I recall correctly.

Simply pass database as argument to each method.

That trades some execution efficiency, convenience and guarantees, for some less memory usage.

Cheers & hth.,

Comment: Thank you for the name of the design pattern I was thinking of.

Answer (score 1):

You say 10000 instances, and yet on a 32-bit system that would only be something like 40K of memory. Unless you're working in an embedded context, I would suggest just storing the pointer in each instance as you've demonstrated in your second example.

This also gives you the flexibility to plug in different databases on different object instances which could enable additional future features.

Comment: its more that I feel uncomfortable duplicating the pointer in each and every instance of the object than the absolute amount of memory.